# Publishing in Visual Studio 2012 - Application Manifest Failed to Download

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, manifest, publish

I'm attempting to publish a C# application through the Visual Studio publish tools. Upon publishing I keep getting the following error log file. Seems like the manifest failed to download despite it being in the installation directory. I've tried various things (including WiX and Install Shield) to try to get around it, but those seem to have their own issues. Found some individuals have similar problems on here, but that dealt with server publishing, and I'm attempting to publish locally onto my computer for manual distribution (limited distribution). Looking for any ideas on how to fix this issue, any help would be much appreciated!

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 10.0.10586.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.6.1038.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    clr.dll             : 4.6.1063.1 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    dfdll.dll           : 4.6.1038.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    dfshim.dll          : 10.0.10586.0 (th2_release.151029-1700)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/XX/Desktop/Training%20Management%20System/Publish9/Application%20Files/Training%20Management%20System_1_0_0_9/Training%20Management%20System.application

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : Training Management System.application, Version=1.0.0.9, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8acccae3f44d0097, processorArchitecture=msil

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Users\XX\Desktop\Training Management System\Publish9\Application Files\Training Management System_1_0_0_9\Training Management System.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading file:///C:/Users/XX/Desktop/Training Management System/Publish9/Application Files/Training Management System_1_0_0_9/Application Files/Training Management System_1_0_0_9/Training Management System.exe.manifest did not succeed.
        + Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\XX\Desktop\Training Management System\Publish9\Application Files\Training Management System_1_0_0_9\Application Files\Training Management System_1_0_0_9\Training Management System.exe.manifest'.
        + Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\XX\Desktop\Training Management System\Publish9\Application Files\Training Management System_1_0_0_9\Application Files\Training Management System_1_0_0_9\Training Management System.exe.manifest'.
        + Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\XX\Desktop\Training Management System\Publish9\Application Files\Training Management System_1_0_0_9\Application Files\Training Management System_1_0_0_9\Training Management System.exe.manifest'.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [1/24/2016 12:20:42 PM] : Activation of C:\Users\XX\Desktop\Training Management System\Publish9\Application Files\Training Management System_1_0_0_9\Training Management System.application has started.
    * [1/24/2016 12:20:42 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [1/24/2016 12:20:42 PM] : Installation of the application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [1/24/2016 12:20:42 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading file:///C:/Users/XX/Desktop/Training Management System/Publish9/Application Files/Training Management System_1_0_0_9/Application Files/Training Management System_1_0_0_9/Training Management System.exe.manifest did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\XX\Desktop\Training Management System\Publish9\Application Files\Training Management System_1_0_0_9\Application Files\Training Management System_1_0_0_9\Training Management System.exe.manifest'.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\XX\Desktop\Training Management System\Publish9\Application Files\Training Management System_1_0_0_9\Application Files\Training Management System_1_0_0_9\Training Management System.exe.manifest'.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
        - Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\XX\Desktop\Training Management System\Publish9\Application Files\Training Management System_1_0_0_9\Application Files\Training Management System_1_0_0_9\Training Management System.exe.manifest'.
        - Source: mscorlib
        - Stack trace:
            at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
            at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
            at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
            at System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async)
            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally got it up and running.

The issue was external. I was using MySQL in the program, however the appropriate dll wasn't transferring. I removed all existing MySQL dlls, and added a new one I downloaded from the Oracle website.